# Getting ERR CERTIFICATE TRANSPARENCY REQUIRED whenever application is opened through automation

Tags: protractor, ssl-certificate, appium

I am trying to test my angularjs application on mobile devices. I have setup all required tools such as protractor, appium, android avd.
When i am trying to execute test scripts, i am getting "your connection is not private".
Appium version - 1.6.3

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7Jp3.jpg)